# Getting a specific value out of array using get_attached_media

Tags: media, array

I'm trying to write a piece of code that fetches the url/download link of any embedded audio files in the current post. In doing this I stumbled upon get_attached_media which outputted something like this (I have removed some of the  values in order to keep it short):

```
Array (
    [172] => WP_Post Object ( 
        [ID]             => 172 
        [post_author]    => 1 
        [guid]           => http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/03-take_me_out_128_lame_cbr_ex.mp3 
        [menu_order]     => 0 
        [post_type]      => attachment 
        [post_mime_type] => audio/mpeg 
    ) 
)
```

As you can tell it is all wrapped in this "WP_Post Object". Now, I'm sure this is all common place and fairly simple to resolve, but I can't figure out how. Essentially, what I want to do is to fetch the "GUID" value and attach it to a variable, as it seems to contain the URL of the post's embedded audio file.

Also, please correct my terminology so I can make this question more useful to others who migh seek an answer to this.

Comment: You normally access this way: `$array[172]->guid` - this is standard PHP. A more lengthy explanation (next to the PHP manual) is here: [Able to see a variable in print_r()'s output, but not sure how to access it in code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6322084/367456)

Comment: Thanks! Let's just say I'm not very fluent in PHP.

What could I substitute "172" with though? I need it to be the id of the currently fetched media/audio attachement. 172 is only specific for one of the posts.

Comment: It's already answered below, that is the ID of the post. Most things have got an ID due to the relational database system running in the background. guids came later and should identify in more open systems like across multiple, independet databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `GUID`. Despite appearances, [that isn't an URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note). Use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src). Something like:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_id,'full');
echo $image[0];
```

Or use [`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) with the post ID.

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_url($post_id);
```

Of course, I don't know what the actual variable name is that holds your images but you should see the ID in the post objects and should be able to work that out. But, for example...

```
$media = get_attached_media(null,1);
foreach($media as $m) {
  var_dump(wp_get_attachment_url($m->ID));
}
```

Comment: `GUID` is the only value that holds the URL and as I will not be changing the contents of it, merely copying them, there shouldn't really be any problems. Right?

I can't use `wp_get_attachement_image_src` since I'm looking for any potential **audio** files embedded in the post contents, not images.

Comment: hmmm... maybe [`wp_get_attachment_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) would be better. I would not use the `GUID` as it isn't really intended to be an URL and WordPress Core may change how that it handled at any time (and I wish it would to avoid confusion).

Comment: That could work! Only thing I need now is to get the id of the audio attachment.

Comment: You have the `ID`. It should be the `ID`s in the post objects.

Comment: No, I need the ID of the media attachment. Those are not the same thing.

Comment: If you used `get_attached_media` as in the question title then they _are_ the `ID`s you need. WordPress treats attachments like a post type.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and you're correct. But `get_attached_media`returns an array. I need to get the ID from that array.

Comment: OK. Processing that array is very basic PHP. See the edit.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! After a bit of tweaking, it now works. Here's the result:  
  
  `<?php $audiostuff = get_attached_media( 'audio' ); foreach($audiostuff as $m) { echo (wp_get_attachment_url($m->ID)); }?>`
  
This outputs the url in human readable form.  
  
And you're right about the PHP, I need to study up on it some more when I have time.  
  
PS. Thanks for the help though! Would be great if you could update/correct your answer so I can accept it as well (I used `wp_get_attachment_url` and not the other one).

Comment: Actually, I meant to use `wp_get_attachment_url` too :)